# Trying to scale from middle with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, scale

I have a little problem with the 'scale' effect of jQuery-ui. When I hide the element (in this case, a red square), it goes from the top to the middle and from the bottom to the middle until it dissapears, but, when I wanna show it, it just expands both vertically and horizontally from the middle and the center. Any clues on how I can do the same animation when hiding and showing?

Here's the code with and the fiddle:

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="position: relative;"></div>
<button onclick="init2();"><<</button>
<button onclick="init();">>></button>
```

JS:

```
function init()
{
    $('#container').show('scale', {direction: 'horizontal', origin: ['middle', 'center']}, 2000);
}

function init2()
{
    $('#container').hide('scale', {direction: 'vertical'}, 2000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yd1y6cbr/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UI seem to be buggy in that effect.. (*it cant scale up vertically*)

But you can use CSS transitions (*a better solution than jquery UI*)

```js
$('.hide').on('click', function() {
  $('#container').addClass('off');
});

$('.show').on('click', function() {
  $('#container').removeClass('off');
});
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 2s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 2s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 2s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 2s;
  transition: transform 2s;
}
.off {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  -o-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="position: relative;"></div>

<button class="hide">&lt;&lt;</button>
<button class="show">&gt;&gt;</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/tcqjuf7j/